# if python assignments don't return a value how can we do a = b = c = 42

Tags: python

After looking at these two questions,

- [Why does Python assignment not return a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869770/why-does-python-assignment-not-return-a-value)
- [Python assigning multiple variables to same list value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857654/python-assigning-multiple-variables-to-same-list-value)

I had this question:

How does `a = b = c = 42` propagate `42` to the left without returning the value at each step?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because of [a special exception in the syntax](http://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements), carved out for that exact use case. See the BNF:

```
assignment_stmt ::=  (target_list "=")+ (expression_list | yield_expression)
```

Note the `(target_list "=")+`.

Answer (score 3):

Chained assignment in this manner **does not require assignment to return a value**. It is a special form of the assignment statement which binds the object to multiple names.

Answer (score 1):

It's a python feature. From [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#numbers):

> A value can be assigned to several variables simultaneously:

```
>>> x = y = z = 0  # Zero x, y and z
>>> x
0
>>> y
0
>>> z
0
```

**Note** that in fact, an assignment doesn't return any value. You cannot do this

```
a = b = (c = 2)
```